# User should view my facebook Wall page, even though they are not logged in?

Tags: facebook

I have a Website, when user click on ( Follow us on Facebook ) button it should link to my Facebook wall page, example ( http://www.facebook.com/totallydriven )

I have added Username as totallydriven in My Account page, 
But when my user clicks on ( follow us on facebook ) button, facebook is asking to log-in to view my wall.

What is the setting I should change.

Some example facebook profile.
Even though you are not log-in to your facebook, you can view their wall.
http://www.facebook.com/HuffingtonPost
http://www.facebook.com/easportsfifa

Answer (score 2):

Try following steps:

1. Log into your facebook account and go to the page.
2. Click Edit Page. You will be taken to the Manage Permissions page. Make sure, for Country Restrictions, you have no countries listed. Listing a country here causes non-logged in visitors to be asked to login, rather than seeing your page as you desire.
3. Remove the countries and click Save Changes at the bottom.

I just figured this out for a page I manage which was doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can control which data you want everyone to use on facebook's [Privacy Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy&section=profile) configuration page. `Posts by me` and `Comments on Posts` are the two most important settings to allow a public Wall.

There is a preview button to see what everyone sees as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like http://www.facebook.com/totallydriven is a Facebook user (hence the button to add as a friend). The others you mentioned http://www.facebook.com/HuffingtonPost and http://www.facebook.com/easportsfifa are Facebook Fan Pages.

Go here http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php to create a Facebook page that users can "Like" and follow as you have described.

Comment: Thanks jcmoney for responding,

If i create a Fan Page, Url will be as this
( http://www.facebook.com/pages/Totally-Driven/132502450121698?v=wall ).

I need the url to be as this 
( http://www.facebook.com/totallydriven ).

Examples such as 
( http://www.facebook.com/HuffingtonPost ) and ( http://www.facebook.com/easportsfifa )
don't have (/pages/) in their URL if they are FB Fan Page.

Comment: Right so a page can have a vanity URL just like a user can. However a page needs a certain number of fans to enable this (I think 25). Go here: http://www.facebook.com/username/ to set the vanity URL for your pages. It will tell you if your page is eligible.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook requires a certain number of LIKES before you are provided a customized facebook URL.
http://www.facebook.com/YOURBIZPAGE